# Using the Gutenberg Editor in Settings Page

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I would like to use the Gutenberg editors useful drag-and-drop/duplicate functionality on a settings page. I'm using the BlockEditorProvider component like so:

```
<div className="svg-list">
  <BlockEditorProvider
    onInput={ newBlocks => console.log(newBlocks) }
    onChange={ newBlocks => console.log(newBlocks) }
    value={ [] }
  >
    <WritingFlow>
      <BlockList />
    </WritingFlow>
  </BlockEditorProvider>
</div>
```

and I'm also enqueuing the registered "wp-edit-post" style.

This *kinda* works, but it messes up some styles and positioning. Ex. The block spacing is off, popovers are sometimes missing a background and/or are in the wrong position, the toolbar doesn't follow you down the page as you scroll like it does in the standard editor.

I've only found a few resources for making a standalone editor, but they seem to be dated already or they import a bunch of stuff that I don't need such as the sidebar/inspector. I also don't want the editor to take up the full screen (there's text above and below it).

Am I missing some components or registered styles? Thanks.

Comment: Want to ask over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I don't, but thank you.